# How to setup a button to link to a textview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a xml file with a few hundred tablerows in which are divided into groups using TextViews.

Is is possible to put buttons at the top  of the screen so when pressed it jumps to the relevant section. (Rather than the user scrolling all the way down the screen the file the relevant section)
Something like a href in html.

Update: to be clearer I want to be able to click on a button on the top of the screen and it must just down to a piece of text I have half way down the screen.

I have a few hundred blah blah  and would like to click something at the top of the screen so that it will jump to the last TableRow for example.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


  <TableLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/txt_color"
            android:textColor="#890000"
            android:height="45dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
      </TableRow>
  <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="9">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/val_951"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/val_919"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:background="#f1b83a"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp">
         </TextView>

         <TextView
             android:text="@string/val_820"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:paddingTop="15dp"
             android:paddingBottom="15dp"
             android:background="#990033"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
             android:layout_weight="3"
             android:layout_width="0dp">
          </TextView>
      </TableRow>



  .
  .
  .
  .
   <TableRow>
   etc etc
   </TableRow>

     </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it but on button click try using

```
 myTextView.setSelected(true);
```